# Vue: pass context to imported component's event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vue-component

Say I'm using an imported Vue component: autocomplete

```
<script>
...
<autocomplete @submit="onSubmit"/>
</script>

...
methods: {
  onSubmit: async(input) => {
     // add user's input to selected
  },
data () {
  return {
    selected: []
  }
},
...
```

I'm passing in a method for the event handler. How can I give it this context so I can update data with input?

Comment: Methods already have `this` context. What problem are you facing? Try writing `async onSubmit (input) {....`, maybe that helps?

Comment: See linked duplicate. Don't declare component methods with arrow functions. Use a regular function instead (as suggested in comment above).